# Sort of Insert/Update statement in LINQ to XML for XElement

Tags: xml, linq, insert

I have this xml structure:

```
<Departments>
   <Department Id="a Guid" IsVisible="True" />
</Departments>
```

I have created the xml file with:

```
<Departments />
```

Now I want to add a bool value to IsVisible for a certain Id

If that Id does not exist in the xml file I want to make an insert creating

a new Department with Id + IsVisible.

My first problem starts here:

```
XElement dep= xDoc.Descendants("Departments").Descendants("Department")
                  .Where(d => d.FirstAttribute.Value == Id).FirstOrDefault();
if (dep != null)
{
    // The node <Department ... /> exist 
}
```

Error message: The Id does not exist in the current context

Of course it does not but that is the reason why I want to check for....

Also how can I check for the Id and compare it with my Id from another List?

Above I ask .Value == Id but I want also compare the value and if its true return the node.

Really I have an XLinq book before me but nothing helped. What a bad buy with non-practical samples (Linq for Visual C# 2008)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that "The Id does not exist in the current context" is actually the error message.

I think it's more likely to be:

> The name 'Id' does not exist in the current context

... which is *very* different. That's saying it doesn't know which variable you're talking about. It's important to quote *exact* error messages.

Now, your question isn't very clear - at one point you're talking about searching for "a certain id" and later you talk about finding out comparing an id with "my id from another list". Do you have a variable with the id you're looking for? Is this just a typo, and it should be "id" instead of "Id"?

Comment: Yes I have a variable with an Id in it. And I want to compare this variable with the ID=... in the xml file.

And yes about the error message you was right. Its "Name Id..."

Comment: @Lisa: What is that variable *called* though. It looks like it's not "Id". Just replace "Id" in your query with the *actual* name of the variable, and it could work... although only if it really *is* the first attribute of the element that you're looking for. (Why not look by the *name* of the attribute?)

Comment: "(Why not look by the name of the attribute?)"

this was my initial Intention but did not know how, so I choosed First() :P